# coreML Failure Verifying Inputs

Tags: swift, vector, coreml

```
let model = test2()
        var data = [1.0, 2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0]

        guard let mlMultiArray = try? MLMultiArray(shape:[1,7], dataType:MLMultiArrayDataType.double) else {
            fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
        }

        for (index, element) in data.enumerated() {
            mlMultiArray[index] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: element)
        }





        guard let markupOut = try? model.prediction(input1: mlMultiArray) else {
            fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
        }
```

I’m using swift 4 and core ML.

Compiles but fails during run time with:

> [coreml] Input input1 is an array of rank 2, but this model only
>   supports single vector inputs (rank 1) or a sequence of batches of
>   vectors (rank 3). [coreml] Failure verifying inputs.

input1 is type of MultiArray (Double 7)

Do I fix the "failure verifying inputs" error by converting the MultiArray of doubles to single vector inputs/ batches of vectors? If so how do I convert a MultiArray of doubles to single vector inputs or batches of vectors?

Comment: Please consider editing the code into the question itself, rather than posting an image of it. That makes it much easier to test it out, and images are inaccessible to screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `shape:[1,7]` the MLMultiArray is of rank 2. Core ML says this model does not support rank 2 inputs. So either do `shape:[7]` (to make it rank 1) or `shape:[1,1,7]` (to make it rank 3).